# Python - Is there a better/efficient way to find a node in tree?

Tags: python, tree, find, traversal

I have a node data structure defined as below and was not sure the find_matching_node method is pythonic or efficient. I am not well versed with generators but think there might be better solution using them. Any ideas?

```
class HierarchyNode():

    def __init__(self, nodeId):
        self.nodeId = nodeId
        self.children = {} # opted for dictionary to help reduce lookup time

    def addOrGetChild(self, childNode):
        return self.children.setdefault(childNode.nodeId,childNode)


    def find_matching_node(self, node):
        '''
        look for the node in the immediate children of the current node.
        if not found recursively look for it in the children nodes until 
        gone through all nodes
        '''
        matching_node = self.children.get(node.nodeId)
        if matching_node:
            return matching_node
        else:
            for child in self.children.itervalues():
                matching_node = child.find_matching_node(node)
                if matching_node:
                    return matching_node
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the other operations you need on the tree, and how often you need to do this recursion, you could store all of the descendant nodes in a dictionary on the node, so this entire recursive function could be a single dictionary look up.

Comment: This recursion will not be called that often as the tree will have only couple of levels with more leaf nodes. Also when you say "store all the descendant nodes in a dictionary" do you mean immediate descendants or all descendants. I am already storing immediate children in dictionary which in turn can have its own dictionary of its immediate children. I need to maintain hierarchy of each sub child. Hope I have tried to explain it properly.

Comment: If you won't be doing this deep search often, then my suggestion wouldn't be good.  I meant that in addition to your dictionary of direct children, you could also store a dict of deep children, essentially, a cache of your recursive search.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind could you please provide your suggestion if this deep search had to be done often? It might be helpful if anything changes in future.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you might be better off using a reusable tree datastructure, rather than reinventing the wheel. The best I've seen for CPython, depending on runtime and workload, are described here:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/

...but in short, the best I saw were the splay tree, AVL tree, and treap.